# Blue Ocean Pipeline editor doesn't start as can't connect to git

Tags: jenkins, github, proxy, bitbucket, jenkins-blueocean

On this [tutorial](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/getting-started-blue-oceans-visual-pipeline-editor), I am stuck at first page where I am supposed to connect to a Git repository. I have tried Github and Bitbucket. For both when I press ok after inputing my credentials, it waits for a few seconds then nothing happens. Not even an error message. I am sure that my bitbucket credentials are correct.

Any idea why?

By the way, I am behind a proxy, which I have setup as usual in the plugns section. I can download plugins so the proxy is correctly setup.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial does use an access key, that is a [PAT (Personnal Access Token)](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/): that means it should net require username/password for GitHub.
Try that (using a key) first.

On BitBucket, the same notion of [access token](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/personal-access-tokens-939515499.html) applies.